# Naturally sort pandas DataFrame by index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dataframe

My dataframe is this form

```
                       material
15N                    649.7
16S                    703.2
16N                    711.7
1S                     716.2
1N                     724.5
2S                     723.5
2N                     721.5
```

I want to sorted the index on the first two numbers  not the first numbers I used the 
code like this

```
runn1.sort_index(axis=0, inplace=True)
```

it sorted on the firsted numbers not the first two number ,I like the data became this

```
    1S                     716.2
    1N                     724.5
    2S                     723.5
    2N                     721.5
    15N                    649.7
    16S                    703.2
    16N                    711.7
```

I am trying to sort on the number before "S" and "N", and additionally if there are ties, I would like them resolved by having the number ending with "S" come first. So in the example above, "1S" comes above "1N".

How do I get this form of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the additional requirement that all "S" come before "N", use the   [`natsort`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module, and pass a `key=...` argument to `natsorted`:

```
natsorted(df.index, lambda x: (x[:-1], x[-1] == 'N'))
# ['1S', '1N', '2S', '2N', '15N', '16S', '16N']    
df.loc[natsorted(df.index, lambda x: (x[:-1], x[-1] == 'N'))]
     material
1S      716.2
1N      724.5
2S      723.5
2N      721.5
15N     649.7
16S     703.2
16N     711.7
```

`natsort` is more generalised for natural sorting problems, and is a handy tool for times like this. Installation can be done using PyPi.

---

If the ordering of "S" and "N" is not important, consider `argsort` for performance:

```
df.iloc[df.index.str[:-1].astype(int).argsort()]
```

Or,

```
df.iloc[np.argsort([int(x[:-1]) for x in df.index])]
```

```
     material
1S      716.2
1N      724.5
2S      723.5
2N      721.5
15N     649.7
16S     703.2
16N     711.7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  and If I let the last char  S always at front of  N  at this sorted point like  1S  1N  2S  2N  15N  16S   16N  , How do we use this  sorted

Comment: @maryadi Please edit your question to include that as a requirement for solving your problem, and I will edit my answer with a solution.

Comment: I used first method but it still  sorted at the first number of index where is my problem?

Comment: @maryadi I have completely edited my answer, please take a moment to go through it once more.

Comment: I use numpy 1.15.4 Is my envroment problem?  My argsort isn't fuction well

Comment: @maryadi No, you must _install_ `natsort` first before you can use it. Run the `pip install --user natsort` inside a terminal.

Comment: The  argsort() isn't function , but the natsort  give the N front to the S   how do we get the S front to the N ?

Comment: @maryadi I hope you read my edited answer which shows how `natsort` can get S "in front" (AKA, _before_ "N").  If you want to change it, use `df.loc[natsorted(df.index, lambda x: (x[:-1], x[-1] != 'N'))]`. Use whichever is correct for you.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC `natsorted` with `reindex`

```
from natsort import natsorted
df.reindex(natsorted(df.index))
     material
1N      724.5
1S      716.2
2N      721.5
2S      723.5
15N     649.7
16N     711.7
16S     703.2
```

Update

```
l=sorted(df.index.str.split('(\d+)([A-z]+)').tolist(), key = lambda x: (-int(x[1]), x[2]))
df.reindex([''.join(x) for x in l ]).iloc[::-1]
     material
1S      716.2
1N      724.5
2S      723.5
2N      721.5
15N     649.7
16S     703.2
16N     711.7
```

Comment: The ordering of "N" and "S" among labels with the same number is important, so you will need a `key` (see my answer)

Comment: @coldspeed yep , fixed :-)